# Dot Sourced Variables VS Global Variables

Tags: powershell, variables, file-copying

I have two ways of referencing script variables from a separate script file. Here are two basic examples:

**1. Dot Source**
Variables.ps1

```
$Source = "source"  
$Destination = "dest"
```

Execute.ps1

```
. .\Variables.ps1  
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination -Force
```

**2. Global Variable**
Variables.ps1

```
$Global:Source = "source"  
$Global:Destination = "dest"
```

Execute.ps1

```
.\Variables.ps1  
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination -Force
```

I have done research but have yet to find a definitive reason as to use one over the other. Are there limitations or cautions I should exercise when using these methods? Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

@mklement0 gave a great answer as to why to use dot-sourcing over global variables. I would love to still keep this discussion open. If there is another point of view, or an explanation as to when using global variables is more beneficial, I would enjoy hearing it and up-voting accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you **use dot-sourcing, *without explicit global variables*** (method 1):

That way, **it requires a *deliberate effort* to add variables to the current scope**. Note that dot-sourcing adds the variables to the *current* scope, which may or may not be the current session's *global* scope (child scopes are created by calling scripts (without dot-sourcing) and script blocks with `&`, for instance).

By contrast, using global variables (method 2) creates session-global variables *irrespective of invocation method*, so that even accidental, non-dot-sourced invocations of the script end up altering the *global* state.

Comment: Interesting. Now would you still suggest dot-sourcing when the variables script file is being referenced by multiple script files? When would using global variables be more beneficial?

Comment: @Ethilium: Yes, let all those script files explicitly dot-source the variables file - that clearly communicates the intent - in the context of the scripts that rely on those variables - and avoids unwanted side effects. Honestly, I'm not aware of use cases where global variables are the right choice (but if there are such cases, I'd love to hear about them). Note that the next level of abstraction would be to create a _module_ that your scripts _import_.

Comment: Thank you for a well explained and concise answer. I will look further into creating modules as well. Marking as correct answer.

Comment: It appears that in PowerShell 6, you cannot access variables that were created within a dot sourced script.

Comment: @DaveF: Does `'$foo="bar"' > t.ps1; . ./t.ps1; $foo` not work for you? You'll only see the variables created in the _script_ scope, not any _function-local_ variables.

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry for the late response. My problem was a bug that relates to assigning objects from imported libraries to variables in a dot sourced script. My intention was to reproduce the problem and report the bug when I got time, but I wasn't able to reproduce it and I won't have time to try further. Global variables was a workaround that I had used.