# importing HTML and outputting with variables

Tags: html, powershell

I'm looking for a method to import a template HTML file in PowerShell and being able to populate it with variables, which in turn sends an e-mail in HTML format containing user data.

I already know how to send the HTML e-mail. And, currently have HTML in a 'here' string embedded in the code. I want to take it a step further, by being able to grab an HTML template based on country code. So, if the user is in the US, it'll get a English HTML data filled e-mail, if they're dutch, they'll get it in Dutch, etc.

```bsh
function SendMessage {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Identity,
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Body
    )

    $Subject = "Important information - Do not delete this email. Welcome to Voicemail"
    $SmtpClient = New-object system.net.mail.smtpClient    
    $MailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
    $CredentialFile = ".\UMcloud-creds.txt"

    $password = Get-Content $CredentialFile| ConvertTo-SecureString -Force    
    $UMCloudAdmin = ""
    $SmtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($UMCloudAdmin, $Password)
    $smtpclient.Host = "smtp-in.net"
    $MailMessage.From = "Voicemail <P@domain.net>"
    $MailMessage.To.clear()
    $MailMessage.To.Add($Identity)

    $MailMessage.Subject = $Subject

    $Mailmessage.Body = $body
    $MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = 1    

    $Logofilepath = ((Resolve-Path .\).Path) + "\logo.jpg"

    $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment -ArgumentList $LogoFilePath
    $attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $True    
    $attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "Inline"
    $attachment.ContentType.MediaType = "image/jpg"
    $attachment.ContentId = "logo.jpg"
    $MailMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

    do {
        $Continue = $false
        try {
            $smtpclient.Send($MailMessage)
            Write-LogFile $OutputLogFile ("[SUCCESS] {0} {1}" -f $identity, $UMExtension)
            Write-LogFile $customemaillog ("[SUCCESS] {0} {1}" -f $identity, $UMExtension) | out-null
            $Continue = $true
        } catch {
            sleep -s 10
            Write-LogFile $OutputLogFile "[ERROR] $Identity $_.Exception.Message"
            Write-LogFile $CustomEmailLog "[ERROR] $Identity $UMExtension"
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }    
    } until($Continue -eq $true)
}   # End send message

$WelcomeText = Get-Content -Path ".\$CountryID.txt"
$Body = @"
<html>
...
</html>
"@
```

The here string is part of the script, I'd like to be able to import it from TXT file as not to clutter the script.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. Please focus on one problem at a time. Show the code that isn't working (a [mcve]), explain what you expect the code to do, and describe what it actually does.

Comment: There is only one problem, being able to populate variables from an imported text file. I have everything else covered.

Comment: Check out the [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx) (`-f`).

Comment: not sure how -f would work in this context.

Comment: `"template string {0} foo {1} bar." -f $var1, $var2`. Works with multiline strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a text file, create a powershell file (ps1) for each html language format you want. Within those files, you can set a single variable as the html text (file EN_US.ps1):

```
$bodyENUS = @"Dear <b><font color=red>user</b></font> <br>
            This is a test <b>HTML</b> email for your language preference<br>
            Sincerely,<br> PdeRover<br>"
```

You can then pass the variable into the main ps file using two ways: Dot Sourcing or using a Global Variable.
**Dot Sourcing**: calling the variable by providing the file name.
In the main file:

```
..\EN_US.ps1
..\PT_PT.ps1

$smtp = "Exchange-Server" 
$to = $Identity 
$from = "Voicemail <P@domain.net>" 
$subject = "This is a Test of HTML Email"
if (user is English speaking){
$bodyByLang = $bodyENUS} 
elseif (user is Portuguese speaking) {
$bodyByLang = $bodyPTPT} 
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $bodyByLang -BodyAsHtml -Priority high
```

**Global Variable**: prefixing a variable with `$Global:`and calling the file during runtime. `$Global: bodyENUS` Then calling it using `$bodyENUS`

I asked my own [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380181/dot-sourced-variables-vs-global-variables) about the difference/best practice of using them. May be worth a read.

This should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is kinda what I was looking for. I'll let you know the results. Many thanks!